# display dropdown list on alert (or on dialog box) in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

My project requirement is to display alert or dialog box on click of button, on that alert, display drop down list with some values, select the drop down list value and save it in array list using HTML. 
i have tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Uj834/)    but it not working.
alert dialog should like below image.

[image: <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console:]

```
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </head>
 <body>

<a data-target="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<div class="modal fade hide" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <select>
              <option>test</option>
              <option>test</option>
              <option>test</option>
              <option>test</option>
              <option>test</option>
          </select>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have bootstrap integrated in your code?

Comment: In Demo link that you provided nothing is wrong. What I can understand is that because of trying to imitate the code from demo link, you might have unknowingly pushed some bug. Post your code, so that it would be easy to help

Comment: yes , i have integrated <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 and <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: Which part exactly not work? the link that you provide already have what you want!

Comment: on click of button, its showing shaded screen instead of alert box.

Comment: I checked your fiddle but its working. So what do you want to do with it now?

Comment: its not working in html code ... it's working fine with fiddle

Comment: try to run the above code same as the fiddle ... its not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code...

```
<a data-target="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

  <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <select>
              <option>test</option>
              <option>test</option>
              <option>test</option>
              <option>test</option>
              <option>test</option>
          </select>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/chandrashekhar/pen/yXNBmQ?editors=1100

here is a link for reference

you have added hide class to modal and also missed some code try this it works..

Answer (score 0):

hi try using http://bootboxjs.com/

Bootbox comes with a Modal With Select Dropdown try using it.

Hope this helps

Comment: you don't see a pop up ? (or) Pop up not closing on save changes button click? what is exact issue? can u explain.

Comment: i can't see the pop up.

Comment: may be js or css issue.. try removing the style.css link in your file.

Comment: may be i am adding wrong js or css file just try that once and suggest me changes

Comment: that code u gave in jsfiddle.net working fine . without any issue. That's the reason i asked you to remove style.css and try

Comment: i tried every think .. code with js and css file, without js and css , other version of js and css file. but it is not working ....

Comment: i think you need to add jQuery 3.1 version or use cdn from this site https://cdnjs.com/

Comment: its not working with jQuery 1.3 also... i have added   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>